# How do I merge .Net 3.5 assemblies with ILMerge?

Tags: .net-3.5, ilmerge

I had trouble with this, and I searched for hours with no answer. I finally figured it out, so I will answer my own question for others to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net 3.5 is merely an extension of .Net 2.0, so use the .Net 2.0 option in ILMerge to combine .Net 3.5 assemblies.